# android difference between cookies and SharedPreferences

Tags: android, cookies, sharedpreferences

I am trying to develop an application where its taking username, first name , last name password from my app send to the server(website).
if that user is not present then it signed up that user, if present then signed in to that user.
All these are working perfectly. Problem is i want to give signout, for that cookie is required to set.

How to set the cookie that i am not getting. or sharedpreference is good?

My code bellow,

```
private boolean sendJsonToServer(String jsonStr) {
        Log.d("sendJsonToServer", "called");
        boolean isDataSend = false;
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

            List<NameValuePair> value = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            value.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", jsonStr));

            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(value);

            request.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse res = client.execute(request);


            HttpEntity httpEntity = res.getEntity();
            String entityStr = convertStreamToString(httpEntity.getContent());

            JSONObject resObject = new JSONObject(entityStr);
            resObject.getString("result");
            resObject.getString("token");

            Log.e("entity", "" + entityStr + "  " + resObject.getString("result")
                            + "   " + resObject.getString("token"));

            Editor edit = prefUserDetails.edit();
            edit.clear();
            edit.putString(TOKEN, resObject.getString("token"));
            edit.commit();

            String token = prefUserDetails.getString("token", "");
            Log.e("token from sharedPreference", token);

                    String[] status_String = res.getStatusLine().toString().trim()
                .split(" ");
            if (status_String[1].equals("200")) {
                isDataSend = true;
                Log.e("isSend", "ture");
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exp=" + e);
        }
        return isDataSend;
    }
```

I am sending jsonObject(jsonStr) which consists of username,gender all details to my server for signup.After signup it signed in and server gives response, one is result and another is token. I want to store that token into cookie.

Then if i press sign out button the token should be remove from cookie.
I am used here shared preference in the above function, but i want cookies to use.

Plz give me a way.
thank you

Comment: with shared preference you do not need handle file I/O.

Comment: To be able to sign out - user must have a (session)cookie already set, which is assumed given when user sign in? But you don't have the cookie, so you are unable to sign out? Is that correct?

Comment: Assuming you don't control the server(website) - check if you can call the url to logout anyhow - if you are lucky it is a simple URL with a 'get' action. It seems to me that you have a working session cookie (are you using WebView?) as ,I understand it, your app do keep you signed in when moving around the pages already signed in.

Comment: I m not using any webview.Just my app interact with the server and get data from server

Comment: Using HttpClient then? The more you tell us, the more likely we can provide you with an answer. Maybe you can update your post with some code, exclude the actual URL if you don't want to post i public.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreference is good option when we aretalking about cookie. As i think you will be storing session related date in cookie and this feature is well supported by shared preference.